# How to write a type test to normalize related types?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to inherit from an external abstract class with methods like this:

```ml
abstract member Plant: KeyValuePair<string, FlowerPot> -> bool
abstract member DigUp: KeyValuePair<string, Flower> -> bool
```

The `FlowerPot` has a property exposing the `Flower`. I don't need the `FlowerPot` itself and would like to write a function that normalizes these two methods so I can directly work with a `string * Flower` tuple instead. I was trying something like this, but I wasn't able to figure out what the type constraint would look like:

```ml
let getFlower kvp =
    let flower = match kvp.Value with
        | :? FlowerPot as p -> p.Flower
        | :? Flower as f -> f
    (kvp.Key, flower)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to write separate functions for handling each type?

Comment: What do you mean by "a function that normalizes these two methods"? Can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have something like this:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Flower = string
type FlowerPot = { Flower : Flower }

type Gardening =
  abstract member Plant: KeyValuePair<string, FlowerPot> -> bool
  abstract member DigUp: KeyValuePair<string, Flower> -> bool
```

The question is whether you can somehow simplify the code that you need to write to extract the `Flower` from one of the two kinds of `KeyValuePair` values (knowing that is is there directly in one and in a nested property in another one).

In practice, (and unless your actual situation is much more complex) I think there is not much to worry about here. Just accessing the different properties is almost certainly going to be the most straightforward (and the shortest) way of doing this:

```
let decideFlower (k, flower) = 
  k = "garden" && flower = "mint"

{ new Gardening with
    member x.Plant(kvp) = decideFlower (kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Flower)
    member x.DigUp(kvp) = decideFlower (kvp.Key, kvp.Value) }
```

You can write a function like your `getFlower`, but this will not be statically checked. You will be able to give it any `KeyValuePair<string, 'T>` including some where `'T` is not `Flower` and `FlowerPot`. To get this to compile, you just need to `box` the value:

```
let getFlower (kvp:KeyValuePair<string, _>) = 
  match box kvp.Value with 
  | :? Flower as f -> kvp.Key, f
  | :? FlowerPot as fp -> kvp.Key, fp.Flower
  | _ -> failwith "getFlower: Unexpected argument"

{ new Gardening with
    member x.Plant(kvp) = decideFlower (getFlower kvp)
    member x.DigUp(kvp) = decideFlower (getFlower kvp) }
```

There probably is a way to do this with more type checking using some static member constraint magic, but I do not think that is worth doing. The above adds a bit of unsafety and does not make your code shorter, so I also do not think it is all that useful - but it compiles.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly my question, thank you! My goal was to make the top-level pipelines as clean as possible, but agree it seems it might be overkill :) And thanks for the tip on `box`; I wasn't aware of that keyword!